Not able to run anything from OpenCV in C++
I've been using opencv with python for a while now (in a venv) and I have to try opencv in C++ for functionnality. However, I cannot seem to be able to run anything.
What was done
I tried installing opencv (4.9.0) manually

I downloaded OpenCV's package, successfully built it and ran a sudo make install
I validated that I had some changed files (local/lib has some libopencv, local/include has opencv4 and opencv2 dir and some cmake files concerning opencv are in local/lib/cmake/opencv (2 or 4).
I placed the downloaded and build package into my project under a thirdparty folder (even knowing it wouldn't change much)
I've tried using find_package, setting the directory to opencv manually using set
After all of this, running cmake and make doesn't crash, but running the executable does.

I tried installing opencv via apt get

I did sudo apt-get install -y libopencv-dev, as well as installed libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config.
I went ahead and fetched/ran the tutorial cpp file and cmakelist file from opencv.
I get a nice error that looks like so:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.9.0) /home/some_username/Downloads/opencv-4.9.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1255: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvNamedWindow'


I did install all of the above, rebooted and nothing changed.

The only thing that works is if I don't use the Gui. However, I want to use it.
I did not provide my cmakefile as anything I would put in there would not change the output one bit, even if it was the makefile from the opencv tutorials.
I'm guessing its some kind of dependency/library problem, but I'm literally out of ideas as to where I have to look anymore. I've been trying to run a single tutorial file for 2 days, using a single library, and C++ is letting me down big time.
I would love some assistance as energy and patience are both running thin.

At step #4 did you clear the cache or delete CMakeCache.txt

I just did and the output behavior is the same.

Possible dupe. If nothing else this demonstrates that the same error can occur with python.

"I did install all of the above, rebooted" its tells you to rebuild OpenCV (with GTK enabled as HighGUI backend)....

@john It's the same underlying C++ library in both cases... doesn't matter whether you call the function directly from C++, via Python bindings, Java bindings, C# bindings, etc. There are likely many more dupes, this gets asked all the time.

I know there are tons of possible duplicates out there, but one of the reason why there are so many duplicates stems from the fact that the answers to all of these duplicates aren't clear at all.

@DanMašek So, if I installed GTK (apt install), and I need to rebuild OpenCV using GTK enabled as HighGUI, could you tell me how I can do as such? Do I need to manually delete the old opencv? Can I just do an apt remove and install? thanks for the support btw!

"I did not provide my makefile as anything I would put in there would not change the output one bit, even if it was the makefile from the opencv tutorials." - Are you using CMake or make? You have tagged cmake and then go on to say "my makefile"...

And even then, assuming you are using CMake, why isn't there a CMakeLists.txt in your question? How are we supposed to reproduce your error if you don't provide us with the tools to do so?

the issue here is how you built OpenCV. this is done based on a cmakelists.txt. this file comes with OpenCV. no user is supposed to touch it. the user is merely supposed to supply cmake variables, when needed, because opencv's cmake file controls the configuration (finding dependencies). so no, posting any cmakelists.txt here would be pointless. we DO need to see the output of the cmake configuration step.

the error message says what to do. if that failed, it's a matter of execution. delete the cmake cache file in the opencv build directory, then rerun the configuration step. use cmake-gui because that is a lot more convenient and powerful than dicking around on a command line (for this task anyway)

when in doubt, abandon C++ and go with languages where all this madness has been taken care of for you, like python. there it's just pip3 install opencv-python to get an officially built package with GUI support. let's face it, if you're interested in OpenCV, you care about solving a computer vision problem, not about grinding your teeth on build problems.

Alright, I'll give it another shot with cmake GUI. I also managed to make opencv work by not using the gui functions, which are the one not being built correctly.
I also agree on your point of using Python. However, the library features I wish to test for implementation are not yet implemented into the python version of opencv.
For a bit more context: I'm trying to detect aruco3 fractal markers, which doesn't seem to be fully implemented into the python openCV as of now. So I have to test using the core package installed locally.

@AndréLehto, if you want to reproduce the error, you really don't need my cmakefile, you can simply take the cmakefile of the basic openCV tutorial, its literally the same.
Now, don't go downvoting a question because you can't figure out the context at a single glance. I'm having trouble installing a library that should not give me trouble in the first place. I don't want whinning, I want answers and good questions such as ChristophRackwitz did.

thrilled to hear your interest in the newest features of OpenCV! if any of those haven't been given the right annotations for Python bindings generation yet, feel free to open an issue about it (unless they already have one for that).

can we assume that you're following official documentation? if yes, that's still no guarantee. docs articles that aren't API are usually not that well maintained. if the screenshots look dated, or the steps look convoluted, it's probably not worth following that specific article.

building opencv should be "just" cloning the repo (git clone of release tag or master), running cmake configuration step, generating build files, building. that should always give you a buildable situation, even if some desirable optional dependencies are missing (like gtk for highgui). -- the cmake magic is supposed to pick up gtk without any hassle. if it didn't, there'd be a lot more complaints, leading to a source-level solution. I haven't built OpenCV in a linux environment, only Windows, and sometimes with Qt (not WinAPI), and I think I had to manually specify a few paths there.

I'm guessing opencv did not pickup some libraries during compilation. Like you said, if highgui or gtk were missing but were optional to opencv, then that would explain my sucess in compiling, building and intalling opencv without issues at first sight.
I'm pretty sure I'll have to wipe my computer as a manual install of opencv like I did isn't easily wiped out. I'll definitely install the GUI packages first and then opencv (using a package manager such as apt).
I'll update if I happen to do so. For now I'll try managing with the opencv without GUI :).
Thanks @ChristophRackwitz !

you can always make install again, then watch where it throws its files, then delete those directories manually. should be just a few directories, and maybe some symlinks, if even that.

I've tried that yesterday, but the same error lingers.

the install part of things shouldn't affect the build part. as long as the cmake configuration step's output indicates "NO" in the GUI section, there's more work to do in the cmake part (cmake variables, if normal find_package fails)

This dude here seems to have managed a build with GTK. maybe something changed in the meantime.

My apologies for the misunderstanding. I was of the impression that you've simply messed up your own CMakeLists.txt, like forgetting to link the library or such. I've removed my down vote.

Thank you @AndréLehto, I appreciate that ! I was a bit dry on the answer as this issue has been gnawing at me a bit now.

Instead of installing it from source you could install it using:
sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv

This should allow you to call find_package with CMake, find and use OpenCV successfully.

fair suggestion, should be the go-to solution for most purposes, except the package isn't maintained by OpenCV itself and usually lags behind releases a bit... and then there is the matter of only getting a "stable" package or else messing with package source definitions (apt stuff). OP did specify that he only bothers with all this to get at some new features. IDK if the ones he wants are in the latest release (which is several months old already), or in a development branch.
